# Generate WP_Query posts with inside while loop and send with Ajax

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to send the data in JSON format by using two loops:

1. Foreach loop for all the terms
2. While loop for posts (based on term id)

but the problem is, I am getting response till `<div class="flex-container">` and I don't know why the execution is getting stopped at `while ($get_offices->have_posts()) :`

I wanted to run WP_Query for inside a loop for each term.

```
function evidian_get_countries()
    {
        $country_list = get_categories(array(
            'hide_empty'      => false,
            'taxonomy' => 'locations-category',
            'parent' => $_POST['region'],
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order'   => 'ASC'
        ));

        // Offices Location
        $terms = get_terms('locations-category', array('parent' => $_POST['region'], 'orderby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => false));

        foreach ($terms as $term) :

            $args_offices = array(
                'post_type' => 'locations',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'locations-category',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms'    => $term->term_id
                    ),
                ),
            );

            $get_offices = new WP_Query($args_offices);
            $offices_data = '';
            if ($get_offices) :
                $offices_data .= '
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button class="accordion-heading active">' . $term->name . '</button>
                    <div class="accordion-content show">
                        <div class="flex-container">';
                while ($get_offices->have_posts()) :
                    $get_offices->the_post();
                    $offices_data .= '<div class="flex-item">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h4 class="location">' . the_title() . '</h4>
                                        <p class="address">' . the_excerpt() . '</p>
                                    </div>';
                    if (has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID())) {
                        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'full');

                        $offices_data .= '<img class="location-img" src="' . $image_url[0] . '" alt="">';
                    }
                    $offices_data .= '
            </div>';
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
                $offices_data .= '</div>
    </div>
</div>';
            endif;
        endforeach;
        foreach ($country_list as $country) {
            $options[] = '<option value="' . $country->term_id . '">' . $country->name . '</option>';
        }
        $data = array('country' => $options, 'offices' => $offices_data);
        wp_send_json_success($data);
        exit();
    }
```

I am looking to get the posts based on custom taxonomy id, I don't understand why I am getting response till `<div class="flex-container">`

Comment: well - it seems like you are resetting the `$offices_data = '';` string before each term, but are not saving it outside the foreach loop - So you will only have the data that the last term contains in your string. and that terms seems to not have any offices. so you end up with only the wrapping flex container

Comment: tro to move `$offices_data = '';` above the `foreach ($terms as $term) :` line